# Why doesn't GCC always emit the atomic builtins?

Tags: c, gcc, built-in, crosstool-ng

Using crosstool-ng, I built a GCC 10.2 cross toolchain for mips-unknown-linux-uclibc. It works flawlessly for the the legacy app I am compiling. I recently tried to compile the the same application for and embedded device running an RTOS using a similar GCC cross toolchain built using crosstool-ng. The main differences are that I configured it to use newlib instead of uclibc and set it up for bare metal instead of linux. The toolchain mostly works but I get the following errors when linking:

```
undefined reference to `__sync_val_compare_and_swap_4'
undefined reference to `__sync_add_and_fetch_4'
```

A quick look at libgcc.a shows that these symbols exist in the mips-unknown-linux-uclibc toolchain

```
dani@ws:~/x-tools$ nm mips-unknown-linux-uclibc/lib/gcc/mips-unknown-linux-uclibc/10.2.0/libgcc.a | grep sync_add
sync_add_and_fetch_1.o:
00000000 T __sync_add_and_fetch_1
sync_add_and_fetch_2.o:
00000000 T __sync_add_and_fetch_2
sync_add_and_fetch_4.o:
00000000 T __sync_add_and_fetch_4
sync_add_and_fetch_8.o:
sync_add_and_fetch_16.o:
```

And not in the mips-unknown-elf toolchain

```
dani@ws:~/x-tools$ nm mips-unknown-elf/lib/gcc/mips-unknown-elf/10.2.0/libgcc.a | grep sync_add
sync_add_and_fetch_1.o:
sync_add_and_fetch_2.o:
sync_add_and_fetch_4.o:
sync_add_and_fetch_8.o:
sync_add_and_fetch_16.o:
dani@ws:~/x-tools$
```

Why does the GCC compiler build not emit the sync builtins when linux is not the target? How do I configure it so that it does? My current hack is to create my own assembly implementations that are identical to the ones that GCC emits in the mips-unknown-linux-uclibc toolchain but would rather understand why they are not emitted in the first place.

Comment: Askl that on `gcc@gcc.gnu.org` [mailing list](https://gcc.gnu.org/lists.html)

Comment: A total guess, but does mips support these operations lock-free, or does it use a lock?  A lock would generally call the OS to sleep if the lock can't be taken, which doesn't work if there is no OS, so maybe those functions are simply left unimplemented in that case.